# Rust - Pass a function reference to threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

Say I have a struct like:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    f: Arc<dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
   pub fn new(f: Arc<dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>>) -> MyStruct {
      MyStruct { f }
   }

   pub fn start(&self) {
      for _ in 0..5 {
        let f = self.f.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let v: Vec<f64> = get_random_vector();
            let v = (f)(v);
            // do something with v
        });
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting an error that the function cannot be shared between threads safely since the `dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>)` type doesn't implement `Sync`.

There is a hack that I can do where I can wrap the `Arc<dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>` in a Wrapper struct and then mark the wrapper with `Sync` using `unsafe impl`. But I was wondering if there is a better solution than that.

Now since the function is inside an `Arc` we have the guarantee that the function value is immutable.

I can also guarantee that the size of the vectors will always be constant for any instance of `MyStruct`. It might be 2, 3, or `n` but it will be the same. So the size of the vector is constant. So the function size is de facto constant.

In fact, if instead of `Vec<f64>` I use `&[f64]` and `[f64]`, the function will still not implement `Send`, even though slices have a definite size.

So why can't the function be shared between threads and what can I do to indeed share it between threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to send an `Arc` to another thread, the `Arc` needs to implement `Send`. If you look at [the docs for `Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) you can see that it has

```
impl<T> Send for Arc<T> where
    T: Send + Sync + ?Sized {}
```

which means that for your code to work, your `T` (`dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>`) needs to implement `Send` and `Sync`.

Since your type is a trait object, what you need to do is declare that, e.g.

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    f: Arc<dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64> + Sync + Send>,
}

impl MyStruct {
   pub fn new(f: Arc<dyn Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64> + Sync + Send>) -> MyStruct {
      MyStruct { f }
   }
   // ...
}
```

as in, the `T` type implements all three of these traits:

- `Fn(Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>`
- `Sync`
- `Send`

Without the `Sync + Send` trait, your `f` function could for instance capture a reference to a `Cell`, which would cause race conditions since multiple threads could potentially be trying to update the value of the cell at the same time. Your code may well not be doing that, but your `start` function has no way of knowing that unless you tell it that `f` is restricted enough to not allow that.