# Share function reference between threads in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to share a function reference between threads but the Rust compiler says `` `dyn for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::string::String) -> std::string::String` cannot be shared between threads safely ``. I'm well informed about `Send`, `Sync`, and `Arc<T>` when sharing "regular" values between threads but in this case I can't understand the problem. A function has a static address during the runtime of the program, therefore I can't see a problem here.

How can I make this work?

```
fn main() {
    // pass a function..
    do_sth_multithreaded(&append_a);
    do_sth_multithreaded(&identity);
}

fn append_a(string: &String) -> String {
    let mut string = String::from(string);
    string.push('a');
    string
}

fn identity(string: &String) -> String {
    String::from(string)
}

fn do_sth_multithreaded(transform_fn: &dyn Fn(&String) -> String) {
    for i in 0..4 {
        let string = format!("{}", i);
        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("Thread {}: {}", i, transform_fn(&string))
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442080/rust-pass-a-function-reference-to-threads But I still want to learn and understand why it's not working the way I thought it would.

Comment: Why do you want to use `&dyn Fn` instead of function pointers? Should `do_sth_multithreaded` work with closures, too?

Comment: It's not a requirement yet, no. Perhaps it could be in future.

Comment: I didn't know about "real" function pointers. It works with this function definition `fn do_sth_multithreaded(transform_fn: fn(&String) -> String)` - thanks! Invocation looks like this: `do_sth_multithreaded(identity);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A function has a static address during the runtime of the program, therefore I can't see a problem here.

That's nice for functions, but you're passing a `&dyn Fn`, and that could just as well be a closure or (in unstable Rust) a custom object implementing that trait. And this object might not have a static address. So you can't guarantee that the object will outlive the threads you spawn.

But that's not even what the compiler is complaining about (yet!). It's actually complaining that it doesn't know whether you're allowed to access the `Fn` from another thread. Again, not relevant for function pointers, but relevant for closures.

Here's a signature that works for your example:

```
fn do_sth_multithreaded(transform_fn: &'static (dyn Fn(&String) -> String + Sync))
```

Note the `'static` lifetime bound and the `Sync` bound.

But while the static lifetime works for this case, it probably means you can't ever send closures. To make that work, you need to use a scoped thread system (for example, from the `crossbeam` crate) to make sure `do_sth_multithreaded` waits for the threads to finish before returning. Then you can relax the static lifetime bound.